# Running a sh script in the background, and adding the job to the list of jobs

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I want to run a NodeJS server for my server.

I installed [Nodemon](https://nodemon.io), and created a script that will run it automatically.

This is the content of my `init.sh` script:

```
nodemon ./index.js > logs 2> errors &
```

But when I run it with:

```
./init.sh
```

And then run:

```
jobs
```

I don't see it in the list of jobs. I have to run:

```
ps -eaf | grep nodemon
```

To get the ID of the job, then kill it.

I've been looking for a solution, and it seems it is related to the context of the shell I'm in (I'm using SSH).

Could someone help me achieve what I am trying to do (i.e. send the job to the list of jobs), or at least point me to the right direction?

Comment: When you say, “… it seems it is related to the context of the shell I'm in (I'm using SSH).” You are mixing up your connection  method (SSH) with the shell which is 100% not related. If your `init.sh` is as it is shown here you are using the basic shell which is `/bin/sh` which can—honestly—be limited. Try adding `#!/bin/bash -l` to the top of your `init.sh` to make the script use the [Bash shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) and the `-l` passes along environment variables which might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jobs` prints jobs of your current shell, while `./init.sh` runs the script within a separate shell. In this separate shell job control is probably disabled, but it doesn't matter because you can't easily use it from your current shell anyway.

To "run" the script in your *current* shell, [source](https://askubuntu.com/a/25530/693277) it:

```
. init.sh
```

This is equivalent to typing the content of the file in your current shell. Then `jobs` should show `nodemon` as a job of the current shell.

Comment: Seems to work, thank you ! What I apparently failed to understand and that I can see now is that the job is actually stopped. is there a way to keep it running ? Also, would you have a solution to avoid having to use the `.` before the command ? I have read about `nohup`, would that solve my issue ?

Comment: @trichetriche Please see [*Linux process in background - “Stopped” in jobs?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17621798/10765659) `nohup` *and* input redirection make the most upvoted answer there, but it's the redirection that does the trick. Note your command may or may not terminate immediately with input redirected from `/dev/null` (I don't know `nodemon`, I'm unable to predict its behavior).

Comment: @trichetriche I don't think you can avoid `.` (or `source`) if you want to use job control of the current shell.

Comment: Nodemon simply is a `node` command with a watcher so that you don't have to re-run your node command at every change. If I got it correctly, I am supposed to redirect the outputs to files, but I'm already doing it, so why would it stop ? Anyway, I've decided to run the command directly for now, as I don't want to focus on line but the JS itself. Thank you anyway for your help, at least i've learn how to source a script !

Comment: @trichetriche You're redirecting *output*. I was talking about redirecting *input*.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry about that, thank you very much :)